# codeigniter uploads directory, unlink photo

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to create the admin panel of my website. I am not using it for the front end because I have lots of static pages in the front end and only a few things need to be dynamic so I will be doing it with core PHP queries.

My link for unlinking photo is , images is the controller and unlinkPhoto is the function and 32 is the image ID.

```
localhost/admin/index.php/images/unlinkPhoto/32
```

### EDIT

however my image is located at     `localhost/uploads/testimage.jpg.`
How can I point to that folder to unlink the image in codeigniter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need to make sure you're enforcing decent security protocols, otherwise anyone can fake the GET request and delete the entirety of your uploaded files. Here is a basic solution:

```
public function unlinkPhoto($photoId)
{
   // Have they specified a valid integer?
   if ((int) $photoId > 0) {
      foreach (glob("uploads/*") as $file) {
         // Make sure the filename corresponds to the ID
         // Caters for all file types (not just JPGs)
         $info = pathinfo($file);
         if ($info['filename'] == $photoId) {
            unlink($file);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you're using PHP 5.4, you might be able to reduce this code down even more:

```
if (pathinfo($file)['filename'] == $photoId) {
   unlink($file);
}
```

Because they've [implemented array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) (finally). Although I haven't tested this particular piece of code. This is just a geeky addendum.

Comment: You can use `pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME)` so no need to fetch the other components and no need for array dereferencing.

Comment: Even better! Thanks cryptic :)

Comment: @hohner But I still cannot unink the image. `localhost/admin/index.php/images/unlinkPhoto/32` is the delete link and `localhost/uploads/testfile.jpg` is the filename. I am still not being able to point to that file with unlink

Comment: I thought you said your files were saved with numbers as filenames?

Comment: @hohner Ya sorry I am updating it,

Comment: Are you storing image records in a database? What does image 'ID' refer to?

Comment: @hohner yea, I am storing the ID and the filename in my database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23535/discussion-between-sohanmax02-and-hohner)

Comment: Well, you'll need to use a `get_where()` and retrieve the filename from the DB record using the ID. Once you have the filename, you can unlink the required file.

Comment: @hohner Yea I retrieved the filename, but when I try to unlink it using `unlink("../uploads/retrievedfilename.jpg")` it still dont work, I think I am not being able to link to the file properly.

Comment: Try using `file_exists()` to make sure the file is where you think it is